# AJAX запрос отсылает пустую переменную в php

Tags: ajax, post, form

Есть форма, с которой берется имя и пароль, отправляется в скрипт и там над ними проводятся действия.И после этих действий происходит переход на другу страницу в случае успешного выполнения. На другой странице мне нужно именно то имя которое ввели в форму прошлого файла.Я пытаюсь сделать это другим запросом, который отправляет это имя в другой `php` скрипт но почему-то, переменная пуста.Что я делаю не так?

Запрос к форме:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/login_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name,
        pass: password
      },
      success: function() {
        document.location = 'chat.html';
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Invalid name or password');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Форма:

```
form method="POST" >
<p class="name_password">Enter your name</p>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="login">

<p class="name_password">Enter your pasword</p>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="login">
</form>
</div>
<input type="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Запрос только к имени формы:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/chat_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name
      },
      success: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Ну и переменная в `php`, она собственно и пустая.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю у вас на второй странице нет `$('#username')`. Вообще такие вещи надо хранить в сессии на стороне php

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev но как же нету, если в первом запросе все хорошо?

Comment: Во втором запросе пользователь на другой странице находится на сколько я вижу (даже если на той-же), поле если даже есть, то оно пустое

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то что вы хотите сделать, то у вас не получится такое реализовать вторым запросом. Вам нужно в первом ajax запросе на success: сделать переход на нужную страницу с get параметром в котором будет имя пользователя, либо на success: повесить событие отправки форм:

```
success: function() {
    $('ваша форма').submit();
  }
```

но для этого нужно подправить форму, дать ей id или submit переместить в саму форму, тогда можно к ней обратится через this, добавить ей атрибут action с нужным путем к файлу и в скрипте события submit нужно передать само событие, и отменить "дефолтное" действие отправки формы event.preventDefault

Но все же это не правильное решение, вам нужно писать имя пользователя в сесию.

Comment: а как писать имя пользователя в сессию?

Comment: Очень просто. В php обработчике (у вас это php/login_script.php):
`<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_name' ] = 'имя или переменная';
?>`
Но лучше почитайте толковую статю по сесиях php. [ссылка](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=070)